# Ubuntu Server crashes on file transfers

Tags: hard-drive, crash, file-transfer, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-12.10

Upon transferring some files across server disks I lost connection and the server crashed. Plugging in a Screen showed no response at all. I had to reset the Server, which then boots normally. At first I thought it was Samba, but I verified today that it also happens when issuing move commands via SSH. I'm running Ubuntu Server off a stick on an Asus C60M-I with 2GB non-ECC memory.

Before this all started, SMB transfers would start fast between server drives (30MB/sec, one drive is SATA, the other is mentioned below is eSATA), but would then slow down to an unreasonable speed, at which point I cancelled the transfer.

After reboot it also appears that I'm getting permission denied errors on all my disks. (when non root) Deluge also cannot write files anymore because of this even tough the mount and all contents are owned by nobody with full access.

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 13 22:40 blastoise
drwxrwxrwx 5 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 02:54 charizard
drwxrwxrwx 4 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 11:15 magikarp
drwxrwxrwx 4 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 10 02:09 raichu
drwxrwxrwx 4 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 14 03:35 ratata
drwxrwxrwx 9 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb  8 19:16 voltorb
```

Here is the Syslog, which seems to point the finger at the first and only partition (ext4) on sdd:

[SYSLOG FILE](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9249086_930_21975224)

Then I've checked this drive with SmartMonTools which aside from having had a high temperature at one point (still within the max of 60°C), seems to be doing ok:

[SMART STATUS FILE](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9249086_930_21975210)

I'm not sure whether to ask this here or at Server Fault, but any help is appreciated. I'm pretty new at this and I'm figuring things out as I go along.

Answer (score 0):

Usually some share of a volume (5%) is reserved for root. How much filled are the volumes? Maybe more than you think due to the copy / move problem. Have a look at

```
df -h
```

This reserved share can be set (to 0%, too) by tune2fs:

```
tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1
```

Force a fsck on all affected volumes in order to rule out file system problems:

```
e2fsck -fy /dev/sdaX
```

Have a look at `top` when trying to move / copy next time. What happens to the load value?

Comment: Space is not an issue.

FSCK:
`e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Raichu: 1000/91578368 files (1.2% non-contiguous), 289042831/366284032 blocks `

Comment: TOP: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9249086_930_21979496
Load keeps climbing the longer the file transfer takes.

Comment: However, it only got to 1.4 - 1.5, which on a dual core should be ok.